# Azure AD authorization token from userid and password flow does not contain roles

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, access-token, roles

I am getting access tokens using both implicit grant and username/password flows with the same user, tenant, and application.  The problem is the username/password token does not contain the roles and I am unable to verify it.  Is there a way I can get a token like the implicit grant flow using the username/password flow?  Examples of each are below

**implicit Grant Token**

```
{
    "aud": "https://<removed>",
    "iss": "https://sts.windows.net<removed>",
    "iat": 1664909167,
    "nbf": 1664909167,
    "exp": 1664913508,
    "acr": "1",
    "aio": "<removed>",
    "amr": [
        "pwd"
    ],
    "appid": "<removed>",
    "appidacr": "1",
    "ipaddr": "<removed>",
    "name": "Test User",
    "oid": "<removed>",
    "rh": "<removed>",
    "roles": [
        "Task.Role1",
        "Task.Role2"
    ],
    "scp": "scope1 scope2",
    "sub": "<removed>",
    "tid": "<removed>",
    "unique_name": "testuser@<removed>",
    "upn": "testuser@<removed>",
    "uti": "<removed>",
    "ver": "1.0"
}
```

**Username/Password Token**

```
{
    "aud": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
    "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/<removed>/",
    "iat": 1664909419,
    "nbf": 1664909419,
    "exp": 1664913431,
    "acct": 0,
    "acr": "1",
    "aio": "<removed>",
    "amr": [
        "pwd"
    ],
    "app_displayname": "test-api1",
    "appid": "<removed>",
    "appidacr": "0",
    "idtyp": "user",
    "ipaddr": "<removed>",
    "name": "Test User",
    "oid": "<removed>",
    "platf": "14",
    "puid": "1003200237B425C1",
    "rh": "<removed>",
    "scp": "User.Read profile openid email",
    "sub": "<removed>",
    "tenant_region_scope": "NA",
    "tid": "<removed>",
    "unique_name": "<removed>",
    "upn": "<removed>",
    "uti": "<removed>",
    "ver": "1.0",
    "wids": [
        "<removed>"
    ],
    "xms_st": {
        "sub": "<removed>"
    },
    "xms_tcdt": 1659020050
}
```

**EDIT...**

Below are the scopes in the app

[image]

This is the curl command used for the username/password flow.  If I specify the scopes in the app, e.g. `scope=scope1 scope2`, then I get an invalid grant error `AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID`.  I do not get an error with `scope=.default`

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=<userID>' \
--data-urlencode 'password=<Password>' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=<ClientID>' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=.default'
```

**More Edits...**
So, this is interesting.  I am now getting the auth token with the following code instead of using postman.  @azure/msal-node returns both the auth and id tokens.  The auth token is the same that is returned from postman and does not contain the roles, however, the id token contains the roles.  Why would the auth token not contain the roles and what can I do to fix this?

```
const msal = require("@azure/msal-node");

const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "<client id>",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>",
    }
};

const pca = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

const usernamePasswordRequest = {
    username: "<username>",
    password: "<password>",
};

pca.acquireTokenByUsernamePassword(usernamePasswordRequest).then((response) => {
    console.log("response:", response);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

**ID token returned from the above code**

```
{
  "aud": "<application ID>",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/v2.0",
  "iat": 1664986457,
  "nbf": 1664986457,
  "exp": 1664990357,
  "name": "Test User",
  "oid": "<removed>",
  "preferred_username": "<removed>",
  "rh": "<removed>",
  "roles": [
    "Task.Role1",
    "Task.Role2"
  ],
  "sub": "<removed>",
  "tid": "<removed>",
  "uti": "<removed>",
  "ver": "2.0"
}
```

Comment: The audience (aud) is different in the tokens. Roles are put into the token based on the target API configuration. Check that you use the same scopes to acquire the token.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @juunas.  Please see the additional info I added to the post

Comment: @juuna Also, I am not specifying the scopes on the implicate grant flow and the token I receive has the correct audience, scopes, and roles.

Comment: If you don't specify the scopes, I assume the access token is for MS Graph API, where the roles won't be. If you acquire an ID or access token for _your app/API that has the roles defined_, it'll contain the roles.

Comment: @juuans No, this is not for Graph but for a second app I registered.  When I get the auth token using the implicit grant flow it contains the roles.  If I get the token using uid/pwd to the same registered app the auth token does not contain the roles but the id token does.

Comment: @juunas It just clicked with me what you were saying about the scopes.  .default scope is giving me access to the default Graph scopes on the registered app, and because of that the aud is Graph's ID with default Graph scopes.  If I specify an app scope it is complaining about not having consent.  If I am not mistaking I think I need to figure out how to specify an app scope and bypass the user consent with the username/password flow.  Thanks for the clues!

Comment: Right, you'll need to first consent through a typical authentication flow or you could do an admin consent for the permissions in the app registration.

Comment: @juunas I have admin consent on scope1 and scope2 and I still get the AADSTS65001 error.  The error also states "Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource".  I have already logged in and consented with an interactive auth but still get the error when I use username/password flow

Comment: @juunas Ok, I just figured it out.  I was just sending the scope name, e.g. scope1.  It has to be passed with the full uri, e.g. https://<tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/<app>/scope1.  What threw me off is that you do not have to pass the full uri for the Graph scopes.

Comment: Right, MS Graph API scopes can use the "shorthand" :)